# Swift Compiler Error : Command /Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I am working with a swift project in Xcode 9. It was working fine and suddenly got some error while running.

> Command/Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 6

[image]

I have tried many ways such as Cleaning the project, delete derived data from Xcode and restarting the Xcode .

But nothing helped for me.

Now Xcode is quiting automatically at regular occations. I have created  another test project. That too showing same issue

Comment: I think you have deleted files and they're previously used

Comment: i never deleted anything @Mannopson

Comment: It's a compiler error. Something went wrong from your side.

Comment: Can you identify what went wrong? @Mannopson

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same error but i have installed Xcode 9.1 which has better performance and stable in compare to Xcode 9 .